# Vuetify form reset impacts parent binding

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am facing a very weird situation with Vuetify forms.  I have a Vuetify data table that follows the example used in the documentation as well as a dialog box that in fact includes a form. I am using prop to pass data from parent to child and I am following Vue and its best practice which consist of using prop as initial value for data variable. I then use to populate the form. I can edit the form and submit new values without any issue, but I created a cancel button that clears the form. when I do that, it also clears the parent fields that are in my data table. it is like the form reset is propagated from the child to its parent. so with the code hereunder, the {{props.item.order.dueDate}} is cleared when I clear the form of the child.v-bind is not supposed to behave like that.

I lost too many hours trying to find a reason but could not find anything
thanks

here is the code of the data table (parent)

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="display-3">
      {{ tableTitle }}
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="search"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :search="search"
      :items="orderItems"
      item-key="_id"
      class="elevation-1"
      :expand="expand"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
        <td class="px-2">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs px-2">{{ props.item.title }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs px-2">{{ props.item.order.date | date }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs px-2">{{ props.item.order.dueDate | date }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs px-2">{{ props.item.count }}</td>
        <td v-if="props.item.status" class="text-xs px-2">{{ props.item.status.type }}</td>
        <td v-else class="text-xs px-2">New Order</td>
        <td v-if="props.item.status" class="text-xs px-2"><span><v-icon color="green darken-2" v-if="props.item.status.signalSent">mail_outline</v-icon><v-icon @click.stop="sendSignal(props.item)" color="red darken-2" v-else>unsubscribe</v-icon> {{  props.item.status.datetime | date}}</span></td>
        <td v-else class="text-xs px-2">-</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
      <template v-slot:expand="props">
        <v-card flat>
          <list-orders-details v-bind:order="props.item"></list-orders-details>
        </v-card>
         <v-btn
          @click.stop="showDialog()"
          color="red darken-2"
          fixed
          dark
          small
          bottom
          right
          fab
        >
        <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-dialog v-model="editOrder" persistent>
            <edit-order-item ref="clearEdit" v-bind:itemChild="props.item"></edit-order-item>
            <v-btn class="cancel" dark color="red darken-2" @click="cancelEdit()">cancel</v-btn>
        </v-dialog>
      </template>
      <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
        Your search for "{{ search }}" found no results.
      </v-alert>
  </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

in the script of the parent:

```
cancelEdit() {
  this.editOrder=false
  this.$refs.clearEdit.clear()
}
```

and an extract of the child :

```
<template>
 <v-form 
  @submit.prevent
  ref="form"
  class="white"
  >
  <v-container>
    <h4>Status</h4>
    <v-divider class="red darken-2"></v-divider>
    <v-layout row wrap  align-center justify-start>
      <v-flex xs12 sm4 md3>
      <v-select
        :items="status"
        v-model="orderItem.itemStatus.type"
        outline
        label="Status"
      ></v-select>
...

    export default {
  name: 'EditOrderItem',
  components: {
  },
  props: ['itemChild'],
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      order: {
        apikey: this.itemChild.order.apikey,
        orderId: this.itemChild.order.id,
        ...
     },
  },

  methods: {
         submit () {
           const formContent = {
            order_id: this.itemChild.order._id,
            item_id: this.itemChild._id,
            order: this.order,
            item: this.orderItem, 
            }
           console.log(formContent)
      },
      clear () {
        this.$refs.form.reset()

      }
  },
```

Comment: I dont see the `cancelEdit()` definition. Would you please add that?

Comment: i just added it, it is in fact in the parent script.